# Re-mount btrfs LXD storage pool to LXD

Tags: btrfs, lxd

I have a Linux system with 2 hard disks, one of them carrying the Ubuntu-flavored linux system, and the other a btrfs-formatted disk carrying the LXD containers.

It was easy to set up LXD to make use of the other (the btrfs) disk for its containers.

What I'm having trouble now, that I formatted & re-installed Linux on my main disk, is making LXD (snap, v5.2) see the containers that are on the other disk.

I tried this command, but failed with an error:

```
lxc storage create default-btrfs btrfs source=/media/karjala/cryptdata/lxd
```

Error:

```
Error: Requested btrfs subvolume exists but is not empty
```

Does anyone know what I should do? Thank you.